# Table cell background color has stopped working for print - all browsers

Tags: html, printing, background, html-table

Table cell background color has stopped working for print on all browsers.

Webpages that I have set up to print had color background attributes. They used to print; today they all stopped working.

I tried to just now create a table using basic HTML - assigned the background color to a cell. It won't show the color when you try to print the page!

i.e.

```
<td style="background-color:#A4FFFF; height:90px; width:90px;">CELL</td>
```

Have I gone mad or did something change overnight?

Comment: Usually the ability to print background colors in an option in your Print dialog or print settings

Comment: Looks like FireFox reset the page setup settings on the last update.. . Can anyone else verify this?

Comment: CSS: box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px gold;
Works on all browsers and will print regardless of the page setup settings - and works on table cells and rows too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure background colors like that get disabled by default to preserve ink...

Comment: Ah! ... Thank you my friend :)
The recent update of Firefox seems to have reset this printer option :)
Saved me a lot of headache today friend :)
I'd be happy to buy you a beer !
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see an CSS style issue. Your width90px has no colon after with 'width' which will break your styles.  Otherwise you can specify a print style in the header using @media queries and adding a class to the cell or table

```
@media print
  {
  table td.myCell {background-color:#A4FFFF;}
  /*or for all table cells*/
 table td {background-color:#A4FFFF;}
  }
```